# (AJAX+PHP+MYSQL) Using a button to delete a record from mySQL using the ID that's listed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've reviewed several issues like mine, and still haven't found a solid solution. I'm trying to use a button that's created by JS with the ID "close" to:

1. close (display:none) it's parent element
2. delete the respective record from the mySQL database.

I think I have 3 pages that are doing the work, and I'm almost positive this can be done in a more simple way.
this is what I have so far:

**my index page:**

```
<?php require_once('../private/initialize.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php include '../shared/headfile.php'; ?>

<body class="body_container">

<div class="container-fluid">
<?php include '../shared/nav.php'; ?>    

<?php include 'checklist2.php'; ?>
</div>



<script src="../public/js/script.js"></script>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>    

<?php include 'action_page.php'; ?>    


</body>
</html>

<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $.post("deletetask.php")
        });
});
</script>


<?php
  db_disconnect($db);
?>
```

This is the checklist that's included (credentials have been removed):

```
<?php 


// Credentials
$dbhost = 
$dbuser = 
$dbpass = 
$dbname = 

// 1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

// Test if connection succeeded
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  $msg = "Database connection failed: ";
  $msg .= mysqli_connect_error();
  $msg .= " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")";
  exit($msg);
}

// 2. Perform database query
$query = "SELECT * FROM task_list";
$result_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

// Test if query succeeded
if (!$result_set) {
    exit("Database query failed.");
}
?>
<body>

<div class="col-sm-9 checklist">
<div class="form-inline checklist">     
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Brevkdown, a CaydenAve app</h1>


<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h2>Organization is important!</h2>
<form id="taskList" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"> 
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Enter Task here" name="task_list">
<button class="addBtn">Add</button></form>
</div>


 <!-- Checklist that shows tasks -->   
<ul id="myUL" class="xmark">
<li>test it</li>    
<?php while($task_list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)) { ?>
<li><?php echo h($task_list["id"] . " " .$task_list["task_list"] . " " . $task_list["task_date"] ); ?></li> 
<?php } ?>
</ul> 

</div>    
<?php
    mysqli_free_result($task_set);
 ?>
```

And my deletetask.php page should have the commands that are necessary to delete the record from the SQL database. Right now, it only has the credentials and connection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're sending a respective ID to be deleted from your DB.
You have a URL but no data being sent to your deletetask.php.

`$.post(URL,data,callback);` is the format you should use.

Beyond that there are a lot of things that you could fix here, you could return values from your PHP and using a callback variable, update your HTML through your JS instead of through your PHP. Separate your concerns

Comment: That's where I got stuck! I don't know how to send the id of the list to the deletetask.php page. Also, i think i understand what you mean by your last statement. Is the way that i did it incorrect? or slower?